# AngularJS: append ng-init to url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to initialize a string with ng-init to append it later on a URL.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="moduleCtrl">
        <div class="panel panel-default"  ng-repeat="x in modules">

          <div class="panel-heading" >
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{ x.id }}">{{ x.name }}</a>
            </h4>
          </div>

          <div id="{{ x.id }}" class="panel-collapse collapse" ng-controller="termCtrl" ng-init="module='{{x.id}}'">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item"  ng-repeat="y in terms">{{ y.name }}</li>
            </ul>       
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('moduleCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://wirtschaftsinformatik.web2page.ch/selectModuleForWebApp.php")
.then(function (response) {$scope.modules = response.data.records;});
});

app.controller('termCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.url = "http://wirtschaftsinformatik.web2page.ch/selectTermForWebApp.php?id_module="+$scope.module;
    $http.get($scope.url)
.then(function (response) {$scope.terms = response.data.records;});
});
```

When I run the code the content inside ng-init doesnt append to the URL. Do you see the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-init syntax in incorrect, currently you have this:

```
ng-init="module='{{x.id}}'"
```

You should have this:

```
ng-init="module=x.id"
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Thx, I tried this out but didnt work too... I need that {{x.id}} expression because I get the data from the other angularjs array.